# Node require on a text file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I had a recent issue with a project where I was using node's `require` function to get the contents of a text file and return a string. It was working fine until a recent build started returning a Module instead of a string. Did something change on Node recently?

Comment: Did the contents of the text file happen to be `module.exports = "some string you were trying to get"`? Because unless that's the case you are definitely mistaken.

Comment: FYI, `require()` has done the same thing from [v0.10.x](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v0.10.x/api/modules.html#modules_modules) to [v11.x](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v11.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_require_id).

Comment: The file itself is just text. They are stored in a Github repo where the main file is a js file with: `module.exports = __dirname + "/samples/";`. But that hasn't changed recently either.

Comment: Closing as off-topic. Lack of [mcve] to reproduce the problem makes this question impossible to answer without simply guessing what happened.